# The React synthetic event onAnimationStart does not appear to fire correctly and does not pass an event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, react-hooks

My goal is to determine if the browser has auto-filled the input field in a form using react hooks. Other stack overflow threads have suggested creating the following in css:

```
@keyframes onAutoFillStart { }

@keyframes onAutoFillCancel { }

.input:-webkit-autofill {animation-name: onAutoFillStart;}

.input:not(:-webkit-autofill) {animation-name: onAutoFillCancel;}
```

This is supposed to create a void animation event that is triggered whenever the browser auto-fills a field.

The [React documentation for synthetic events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#animation-events) suggests using a synthetic event such as onAnimationStart. The name of the transition can be discovered with the property animationName.

I cannot get this to work. There appears to be two problems. onAnimationStart is not triggered when the field is autofilled. It appears to trigger every time the element is rendered. Also, onAnimatinoStart does not return the event, it returns an object of all the elements that have this event.

I have tried several options:

Option 1:

```
<input onAnimationStart={console.log(e)}/>
```

This logs an object for each element that has this event. The objects are logged every time the elements are rendered.

Option 2:

```
<input onAnimationStart={console.log(e.target)}/>
```

Similar behavior as option 1, however output is undefined

Option 3:

```
<input onAnimationStart={handleAnimation(e)}/>
const handleAnimation = (e) =>{console.log(e)}
```

Behaves like option 1

Option 4:

```
<input onAnimationStart={handleAnimation}/>
const handleAnimation = () =>{console.log"foo bar"}
```

"foo bar" does not get logged to the console.

Option 5:

```
<input onAnimationStart={(e) => handleAnimation(e)}/>
const handleAnimation = (e) => {console.log("foo bar " + e)}
```

Behaves like option 4.

I have also tried the same options replacing onAnimationStart with
onAnimationStartCaputure. The results are identical.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the native event as a child of the synthetic event

```
const handleAnimation = (e: any) => {
  console.log(e.nativeEvent.animationName);
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <input
          id="email"
          name="email"
          className="input"
          onAnimationEnd={(e) => handleAnimation(e)}
           onAnimationStart={(e) => handleAnimation(e)}
        />
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-dawn-e0ey7?file=/src/App.tsx:24-429
Press tab on the email to trigger the auto fill

Comment: Thanks for the help Your code sandbox solution works in that environment. It tried incorporating it in my code and the console.log is still not logging anything. How important is the argument (e: any). Visual studio is flagging this as a Typescipt argument. I have not installed this library.

Comment: replace (e: any) with (e).
Please upvote if it works.

Comment: I tried and it did not work. I also tried the following: <input onAnimationStart={console.log(e.nativeEvent)}/>. The result looks like option 1, above except that it logs "undefined"  to the console. I must have a missing library or something. The syntax of the code you provided looks just like the syntax shown in option 5. It is the same syntax I am using for onClick, onBlur, etc. I am not sure why this expression does not log anything whereas options 1 & 3 do.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response. onAnimationStart is a callback function. So you need to pass a function. You also need to define the parameter which can be called anything. onAnimationStart={(anything) => console.log(anything.nativeEvent)}

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I tried your suggestion. onAnimationStart and onAnimationEnd are not firing. This result is similar to the option 5 listed above. I will try some other possibilities and get back.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your example code showed me what I was doing wrong. The issue turned out not to be a nativeEvent issue. The issue was that I did not correctly wire the component to the animation class name trigger. Once the animation class name was included in the component, it passed the event as one would expect.